# Move file into a specific folder

Tags: php

I have a question regarding file handle, i have:

Files:
 "Mark, 123456, HTCOM.pdf"

"John, 409721, JESOA.pdf

Folders:

"Mark, 123456"

"Mark, 345212"

"Mark, 645352"

"John, 409721"

"John, 235212"

"John, 124554"

I need a routine to move files to correct folders.
In case above, i need to compare 1st and second value from file and folder. If are the same i move the file.

Complement to post:
I have this code, work right but i need to modify to check name and code to move files...
I'm confused to implement function...

```
$pathToFiles = 'files folder'; 
$pathToDirs  = 'subfolders'; 
foreach (glob($pathToFiles . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.pdf') as $oldname) 
{ 
    if (is_dir($dir = $pathToDirs . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . pathinfo($oldname, PATHINFO_FILENAME)))
     { 
        $newname = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . pathinfo($oldname, PATHINFO_BASENAME);


        rename($oldname, $newname); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: yes, sorry, i have posted code also...

Answer (score 0):

As a rough-draft and something that will only work with your specific case (or any other case following the same naming pattern), this should work:

```
<?php
// define a more convenient variable for the separator
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

$pathToFiles = 'files folder';
$pathToDirs = 'subfolders';

// get a list of all .pdf files we're looking for
$files = glob($pathToFiles . DS . '*.pdf');

foreach ($files as $origPath) {
    // get the name of the file from the current path and remove any trailing slashes
    $file = trim(substr($origPath, strrpos($origPath, DS)), DS);

    // get the folder-name from the filename, following the pattern "(Name, Number), word.pdf"
    $folder = substr($file, 0, strrpos($file, ','));

    // if a folder exists matching this file, move this file to that folder!
    if (is_dir($pathToDirs . DS . $folder)) {
        $newPath = $pathToDirs . DS . $folder . DS . $file;
        rename($origPath, $newPath);
    }
}
```